# Pandas test if one column is a subset of another column? (i.e. column B contains column A)

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'COL1':['United States of America', 'United Kingdom'], 'COL2':['States of America', 'United States']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df['IS_COL1_IN_COL2'] = df['COL1'].isin(df['COL2'])
display(df)
```

The code above is giving the result below. I expected the values to be False, but I'm getting True? Can you please let me know what's wrong in my code? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You wrote COL1 twice, I’m guessing you meant to write COL2? Reading the accepted answer, I don’t think it’s even clear what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Thanks..you're right I've fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `in` with lambda function:

```
df['IS_COL1_IN_COL2'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['COL1'] in x['COL2'], axis=1)
df['IS_COL2_IN_COL1'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['COL2'] in x['COL1'], axis=1)

print (df)
                       COL1               COL2  IS_COL1_IN_COL2  \
0  United States of America  States of America            False   
1            United Kingdom      United States            False   

   IS_COL2_IN_COL1  
0             True  
1            False
```

---

Function [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) working different - it compare each value of `COL1` by all values of `COL2`, check changed data sample:

```
data = {'COL1':['United States of America', 'United Kingdom','USA','JAR'], 
        'COL2':['States of America', 'United States','UK', 'USA'],} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

df['IS_COL1_IN_COL2_isin'] = df['COL1'].isin(df['COL2'])
df['IS_COL1_IN_COL2'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['COL1'] in x['COL2'], axis=1)
df['IS_COL2_IN_COL1'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['COL2'] in x['COL1'], axis=1)
print (df)
                       COL1               COL2  IS_COL1_IN_COL2_isin  \
0  United States of America  States of America                 False   
1            United Kingdom      United States                 False   
2                       USA                 UK                  True   
3                       JAR                USA                 False   

   IS_COL1_IN_COL2  IS_COL2_IN_COL1  
0            False             True  
1            False            False  
2            False            False  
3            False            False
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But I was trying to understand why is the .isin not working. Any idea?

Comment: @ShadyMBA - Yop, check last sentence. also if use `df['COL1'].isin(df['COL2'])` it working differently - it compare eachvalue of `COL1` by all values of `COL2`. My solution above compare in pairs by rows.

Comment: @ShadyMBA - Is possible improve performance by `df['IS_COL2_IN_COL1'] = [a in b for a, b in df[['COL2', 'COL1']].to_numpy()]` or `df['IS_COL2_IN_COL1'] = [a in b for a, b in df[['COL2', 'COL1']].values]` for oldier pandas versions